# iOS feature, script or app to quickly determine who's calling based on AI search of the internet?

Tags: iphone, ios, automator, script, siri

Most the time when I get a call from a random number, I ignore it, google it, and call them back if I recognise it’s from someone relevant.

This process is annoyingly cumbersome for something I might do a few times a week, and worse when I only have a mobile (as opposed to laptop, where I can work faster).

Is there an app or built in iOS feature that does this for me? I might start experimenting with bard or chatGPT. All I really do is to see if the number matches a person or institution that I recognise (e.g. a bank, hospital, colleague), or instead the number might show up on spam call reporting site, which lets users say they got a spam call from that number and list details about who it was.

Some automated (AI) process that's correct ~90% of the time would be an amazing improvement on my currently finicky and manual process.

I don't mind if it's hard to setup, e.g. a script on iPhone along the lines of asking Siri to ask ChatGPT who's currently calling, perhaps with a bunch of pre-set prompt instructions like (search the web for , if that doesn't yield a result, search with natural number breaks (e.g. "`1234567890`" vs "`12 3456 7890`" or "`12-3456-7890`" etc (that's what I do manually if I initially can't find the number).

Comment: What you’re asking is probably not possible, but you can add the numbers you want to answer to your contacts, and set the phone to ring only when the call comes from one of those numbers.

Comment: Apps can link into the phone app to automatically look up phone numbers of callers. I have installed one for the Swiss phonebook, maybe a similar app is available in your country?

Comment: You mention a few times a week, Personally, I dont think that justifies the effort of doing what you are proposing.  Since displayed phone numbers can be spoofed, I don't always answer international numbers or numbers that look wrong - such as too many digits for local mobile numbers.  When I am suspicious, I just ignore it the first time.  But I answer it the second time.  I also have DO Not disturb set up so that calls from only selected  family members will make the phone ring.

Comment: @RohitGupta when someone spoofs the number, they are usually lazy and spoof the same number for all the people they're spamming, which means those websites that let users report random spam calls usually pick them up rapidly (e.g. often I google a number and see that it was used to spam others just a few minutes prior). So even if the spammer spoofs numbers, so long as they're not clever enough to spoof *different* numbers for each call (they usually aren't), then googling the number can be helpful.